# Tkinter Multiframe event

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to GUI by Tkinter. This code as below
target is show message "This page xxx" every 1 second. when i open each frame same

1. when i open page one will be show message "This is page one" every 1 second
2. when i open page two will be show message "This is page two" every 1 second (don't show message page one)

(Sorry all i explain English language not good)

```
import Tkinter as tk
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self, bg='red')
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        self.val1 = "chain"

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.collection = (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo)

        for F in self.collection:
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def printdata(self, data):
        print data


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.master = controller
        self.configure(background='green')
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2", command=lambda: self.gopagetwo())
        button2.pack()

    def gopagetwo(self):
        PageTwo.mymessage()
        self.master.show_frame(PageTwo)

    def mymessage(self):
        print 'This is page initial.'
        self.after(1000, self.mymessage)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='yellow')
        self.master = controller
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.label.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
        self.lblCounter = tk.Label(self, text="Counter", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.lblCounter.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
        self.lblStartTime = tk.Label(self, text="time start", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.lblStartTime.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
        self.lblStartNow = tk.Label(self, text="time now", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.lblStartNow.pack(pady=5,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

    def mymessage(self):
        print 'This is page one.'
        self.after(1000, self.mymessage)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='pink')
        self.master = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
        self.lblCounter = tk.Label(self, text="Counter", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.lblCounter.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
        self.lblStartTime = tk.Label(self, text="time start", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.lblStartTime.pack(pady=5,padx=10)
        self.lblStartNow = tk.Label(self, text="time now", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.lblStartNow.pack(pady=5,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

    def mymessage(self):
        print 'This is page two.'
        self.after(1000, self.myssage)


app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what is the problem/question? The code does not work, you get errors, if so, which ones?

Comment: Yes i have question. When i press button page one on start page and page one is show up and i want send message "This is page one" immediately and cancel when comeback to start page again.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand your code. It seems incomplete. What is `self.mastermessage`? it is not initialized nor defined in the code you provided. Also the code returns error when pressed second button due to this `PageTwo.mymessage()`.

Comment: Since PageOne and PageTwo are in separate frames you can destroy/iconify/pack or grid_forget PageOne so it won't show when PageTwo is called

Comment: I'm sorry please change self.mastermessage to self.mymessage. From my code i would like to send message "This is page xx" every time when i opened current frame. From my code i try to create method mymessage for loop send the message when that page is active .

Comment: Do you have any idea to show message when page is active?

Answer (score 0):

There a few problem in your code.

First, in `StartPage.gopagetwo`, the invocation of `PageTwo.mymessage()` can not work since mymessage is an instance method, it needs a PageTwo instance to work properly.

You might try to reach the behavior you want by adding a call to `frame.mymessage()` in `Application.show_frame`. However, you will find out that it does not print a message for the current frame, but for each visited frame (and one by visit). If you follow this track, you will have to store somewhere the binding of after, and offer an option to abort it.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    #...
    def mymessage(self):
        print 'This is page initial.'
        self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.mymessage)

    def end_mymessageloop(self):
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

and adapt `show_frame`:

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    #...
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        if hasattr(self,"current_frame"):
            self.current_frame.end_mymessageloop()
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.mymessage()
        self.current_frame = frame
```

---

However, you may find simpler to have only one instance of this after loop that delegate the print statement to your frames (and remove the looping after in each mymessage).

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #...
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        self.status_message()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        self.current_frame = frame

    def status_message(self):
        self.current_frame.mymessage()
        self.after(1000, self.status_message)
```